# UInavigation popping back view and updating previous view's content

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uicollectionview, viewwillappear

I have a collection view with cells that can be tapped, and push to a second view. The problem is, the changes I make in the second view are suppose to alter the first view(collection view) when the user pops back to it. By adding a new cell with an image.I can't seem to get the content to update.

I tried to use viewWillAppear on the first view and [colectionview reloadData] it doesn't seem to work. Anyone got a fix for this? help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should share how the second view controller provides the first view controller the updated information, because `viewWillAppear` is a fine time to update the first view controller's view. Set a breakpoint/log message to make sure it's getting called, but more likely, the underlying model is not getting updated for some reason.

Comment: Ok I'll edited it right away

Comment: Put First and Second ViewController code in your question. This seems to be easy fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem By calling [collectionview reloadData] in viewDidAppear instead of viewWillAppear, only problem is there is a noticeable amount of lag before the cell appears. Anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Have you debugged either UIcollectionViewDataSource methods are being called? Make sure you have set the delegate and datasource off collection view. What is the data source of collection view? Please paste your code of second view where you are making changes.